# Cannot satisfy protocols (with associatedtype) comformance

Tags: ios, swift, generics, clean-architecture

I'm working with `CleanSWift` in my new project and I'm facing that it's too wordy. To automate some of the basic stuff, I wrote following tools (simplified):

```
// MARK: - Presenter

protocol Presenter {
    associatedtype DisplayLogic
    var viewController: DisplayLogic? { get set }
}

protocol PresentationLogic {
    func show(_ error: Error)
}

extension PresentationLogic where Self: Presenter, Self.DisplayLogic: DefaultDisplayLogic {
    func show(_ error: Error) {
    }
}

// MARK: - Display logic

protocol DefaultDisplayLogic: class {
//    func present(_ error: Error)
}

protocol TableViewDisplayLogic: DefaultDisplayLogic {
//    func reloadTableView(with sections: [Section])
}
```

When I try to implement the code above, generics seems to be broken. I'm getting an error saying "Type 'MyPresenter' does not conform to protocol 'PresentationLogic'." However, everything seems fine to me.

```
// MARK: - Controller

protocol MyDisplayLogic: DefaultDisplayLogic {
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, MyDisplayLogic {
}

// MARK: - Interactor

protocol MyBusinessLogic {
}

class MyInteractor: MyBusinessLogic {
    var presenter: MyPresentationLogic?

    func test() {
        presenter?.show(TestError.unknown)
    }
}

// MARK: - Presenter

protocol MyPresentationLogic: PresentationLogic {
}

class MyPresenter: Presenter, MyPresentationLogic {
    weak var viewController: MyDisplayLogic? // ** Here I get the error. **
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, `MyPresenter` doesn't fulfill the requirements of the where clause of the `PresentationLogic` extension, so it can't use the default implementation of `show(_:)`. Specifically, it doesn't pass the test for `Self.DisplayLogic: DefaultDisplayLogic`. Therefore, it doesn't conform to `PresentationLogic`, and so it also doesn't conform to `MyPresentationLogic`, which inherits from `PresentationLogic`.

But why not? I think it's caused by how Swift works: protocols can't conform to themselves. In `MyPresenter`, `Self.DisplayLogic` is `MyDisplayLogic`. Though it is a descendent protocol of `DefaultDisplayLogic`, it still seems to function as "a protocol trying to conform to itself", so it doesn't work.

To demonstrate this, you can replace `weak var viewController: MyDisplayLogic?` with `weak var viewController: MyViewController`, and the error will go away, since it's a concrete type that conforms to `DefaultDisplayLogic`. Also, if you change `Self.DisplayLogic: DefaultDisplayLogic` in the where clause to `Self.DisplayLogic == MyDisplayLogic`, the error will go away because you are requiring a specific type rather than a conformance.

In your case, a possible solution is to make `MyPresenter` a generic class. For example:

```
class MyPresenter<ConcreteDisplayLogic: DefaultDisplayLogic>: Presenter, MyPresentationLogic {
    weak var viewController: ConcreteDisplayLogic?
}
```

That will allow you to use the same where clause constraints for your default implementation of `show(_:)`, while providing a type-safe, generic implementation of `MyPresenter`.

There is a limitation to this approach: you can't change the type of the value of `viewController` for a single instance of `MyPresenter`.